# Filter using a CheckboxSelectMultiple returned from a form in django

Tags: django

I have a a form which contains a field :

```
item = forms.MultipleChoiceField( widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=ITEM_CHOICES)
```

on the POST operation in my view, when I get the form back. I thought that the form.data['item'] should contains a dict, but it doesnt. it holds only the higher item_value.

how can I get the multi selection from the POST operation then ?

on my views.py

```
search_items_form = SearchItemsForm( data = request.POST )
if not search_items_form.is_valid():
    ...error...
if 'item' in search_items_form.data:
     item = search_items_form.data['item']
```

here item equal *only* to one value while you can see in the field form it is set as multiplechoicefield.

also, when looking at firebugs I see over the parameter is the POST operation :
item 1
item 2 
item 3
item 4

so the POST does contains multiple item X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be accessing `cleaned_data['item']`, not `data['item']`.

Comment: there is no such thing as cleand_data in a form object.. there is a full_clean , but it doesnot work .

Comment: Well, seems like I am doing somthing wrong here because cleaned_data should be valid here. however, it isn't. I am getting an error that there is no such attribute in my form...

Comment: The reason I have no cleaned_data is because the is_valid return false. I had a bug which I didnt return after that and only post HttpResponse. I'll fix that and see whats going on.